# Punching - Force or Momentum?

Tags: forces, everyday-life, momentum, acceleration

If I want to punch a person inflicting maximum damage, what do I need to care about?

My force of punching, i.e, do I need more acceleration? Or do I need momentum, i.e my velocity for punching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end it is the (kinetic) impact Energy $E=\frac{p^2}{2m}$ that counts, so you'll need a high momentum. However, to create this momentum you'll need force since $F=\frac{d}{dt}p$. In other words, the more the impact velocity, the more damage, but to create this velocity, you'll need acceleration

Comment: In other words, the more my hand accelerate, the more damage it does, right?

Comment: yes, sounds plausible, doesn't it? :)

Comment: This kind of analysis is deeply lacking. Neither the fist nor the target are free, the collision is not allowed to develop in it's own time but is affected by follow-through and recovery on the part of the puncher and by avoidance, slipping, flinching or rolling-with on the part of the punchee.

Comment: @dmckee What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that this answer is more of less correct if you were taking the fist off your wrist and *throwing* it at your opponent, but a punch is delivered by a puncher in contact with the ground. A significant part of what boxers and other martial artists learn is how to punch well: how to set up your skeletal alignment so that you can use your shoulders, chest, abs, back and *legs* to power the punch, ultimately pushing off of the ground to do it. None of which is captured in this answer.

Comment: @dmckee The question wasn't about anatomy, it was simply about which physical quantity needs to be maximized to induce the most damage with a punch. Your considerations are true, but they aren't the answer to the question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Momentum.

It's all momentum, you want to use your legs, shoulder and hip all to be "behind" your punch so that it has more momentum. You also want your hand to be continuously accelerating from the start to the end of the punch, as this will create more momentum by increasing velocity.

Increasing mass also helps with impact. So, increasing the size of your forearm for example increases impact energy. The goal is to transfer as much energy from you to your opponent that is possible. I mean "energy" in the strict sense.